# convert varchar to date and order by converted varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello Im having problem my friend resist to change the data type of the field to date so im havin a problem using order by, here is the sample data 04-07-2016(mm-dd-yyyy) and the field name called regis_date, and the table name is users, and here is my query.

```
SELECT regis_date FROM users ORDER BY regis_date DESC
```

output :

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#625 (1) {
    ["regis_date"]=>
    string(10) "04-09-2016"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#622 (1) {
    ["regis_date"]=>
    string(10) "04-08-2018"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#624 (1) {
    ["regis_date"]=>
    string(10) "04-07-2016"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#627 (1) {
    ["regis_date"]=>
    string(10) "04-07-2016"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#621 (1) {
    ["regis_date"]=>
    string(10) "04-06-2017"
  }
}
```

as you can see, the query is not correct, then after googling i try this one

```
SELECT regis_date FROM users ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(regis_date,'%m-%d-%Y') DESC
```

and this

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, regis_date, 120) FROM users ORDER BY regis_date
```

but the output was NULL :'(

Answer (score 0):

Please give it a try:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(regis_date,'%m-%d-%Y') as dt 
FROM users 
ORDER BY dt DESC
```

**Note:** You were ordering the result by `VARCHAR` column. So, you will get result based on `String` ordering. So, here I've converted your `varchar` to `DATE` and later sorted the result set based on this date object.

Comment: Please show me some sample data of `regis_date` column.

Comment: 04-07-2016, 04-08-2018, 04-06-2017, 04-07-2016, 04-09-2016

Comment: Are you sure the data in `regis_date` column in this format (`Month-day-year`) ?

Comment: Can you share an **SQL FIDDLE** ?

Comment: He would have to use those date examples, huh? And not `30-04-2016` :p